# How I can set background color of row in google sheet with python

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

I have some code that adds new data to a google spreadsheet.

I am adding a new line with below code.

```
sheet.insert_row(row)
```

And I want to set the background color of this row to green.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit this as it uses poor English skills, making it difficult to read / understand.

Comment: @taylor.2317 that's better?

Comment: Yes, thanks, much better :)